# how to hide label?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

As you can see, i have a list of collection view here, and some product are having promotion price and some are not. For those product which having promotion, it will display the red colour price with the actual price strike through with it(beside). The problem now is, i was passing all these value from previous view using segue, now i have to hide promotion price label for those product which not having promotion price, how should i do it?

[hide label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN4rj.jpg)

Here is the code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SubCategoryDetailsCollectionViewCell

    let grey = UIColor(red: 85.0/255.0, green: 85.0/255.0, blue: 85.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    cell.layer.borderColor = grey.CGColor

    cell.titleLabel.text = name[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: thumbImg1[indexPath.row] ))
```

I try to hide the label in this way, but its not really working, 
it work for awhile and after i start scrolling my collection view, all promo label is hidden

```
    if promo[indexPath.row] == "0"{

        cell.promoLabel.hidden = true
    }else{
        cell.promoLabel.text = "RM" + promo[indexPath.row]
    }

    cell.priceLabel.text = "RM" + price[indexPath.row]

    cell.productLabel.text = label[indexPath.row]

    cell.setNeedsDisplay()
    return cell
}
```

Comment: can you show us some of your code? it's quite hard to guess it...

Comment: @elyashiv i updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
if promo[indexPath.row] == "0"{
    cell.promoLabel.hidden = true
}else{
   cell.promoLabel.hidden = false
    cell.promoLabel.text = "RM" + promo[indexPath.row]
}


cell.productLabel.text = label[indexPath.row]

cell.setNeedsDisplay()
return cell
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can hide label by changing alpha value also. Try

```
cell.priceLabel.alpha = 0 //to hide
cell.priceLabel.alpha = 1.0 //to show
```

Comment: Debug and find which line in executing. I mean check which one is working if statement or else statement. May be some error in that

Answer (score 0):

> This problem occurs because of cell reusing

Try this code:

```
if promo[indexPath.row] == "0" {
   cell.promoLabel.hidden = true
}
else {
   cell.promoLabel.hidden = false
   cell.promoLabel.text = "RM" + promo[indexPath.row]
}
```